# Hyperthreading can only create two threads?

Tags: multi-core, hyperthreading

HyperThreading can only create two cores/threads ?

More can not be created by design or is there any other limitation ?

Comment: why is this question down-voted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HyperThreading is Intel's name for multiple run queues on single processor core. For now Intel only have processors with 2 threads, but other architectures has more, e.g. IBM power 7 have 4 threads.

Comment: On top, this is hardware threads. The OS can schedule multipel software threads like with a real core. It is only called hardware thread becuase it is not a "full core" - some stuff is shared, when access is needed the small hyper-threading core must wait.

Comment: I like definition of 'execution thread', 'hardware thread' is a bit misleading

Comment: Agree, but it is like what you find in most discussions. "Hardware side numlti threading".